# Exchange Web Services get appointment as MIME

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices, icalendar

I'm trying to get iCal from EWS appointment (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-export-items-by-using-ews-in-exchange).
In general it's works fine, but something goes wrong when appointment is recurring with modified occurrences (exceptions), them MIME content received on master recurring event contains all it's modified occurrences :

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
METHOD:PUBLISH
PRODID:Microsoft Exchange Server 2010
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Israel Standard Time
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:16010101T020000
TZOFFSETFROM:+0300
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=10
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:16010101T020000
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0300
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=-1FR;BYMONTH=3
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
ORGANIZER;CN=Slava:mailto:slava@domain.onmicrosoft.com
ATTACH:CID:408BD82990C789226A32C4E6F8D7E592D9DD5960@eurprd01.prod.exchangel
 abs.com
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20200401T050000Z;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=WE;WKST=SU
UID:040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00800000000D263C072E37DD501000000000000000
 01000000021933B3497010A43A59A900692A1BE23
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-US:Recurrent 1
DTSTART;TZID=Israel Standard Time:20191009T080000
DTEND;TZID=Israel Standard Time:20191009T083000
CLASS:PUBLIC
PRIORITY:5
DTSTAMP:20200401T060210Z
TRANSP:OPAQUE
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SEQUENCE:0
LOCATION;LANGUAGE=en-US:
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-APPT-SEQUENCE:0
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-OWNERAPPTID:2117746898
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INTENDEDSTATUS:BUSY
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-ALLDAYEVENT:FALSE
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INSTTYPE:1
X-MICROSOFT-DONOTFORWARDMEETING:FALSE
X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:FALSE
X-MICROSOFT-LOCATIONS:[]
BEGIN:VALARM
DESCRIPTION:REMINDER
TRIGGER;RELATED=START:-PT15M
ACTION:DISPLAY
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00800000000D263C072E37DD501000000000000000
 01000000021933B3497010A43A59A900692A1BE23
RECURRENCE-ID;TZID=Israel Standard Time:20191023T080000
SUMMARY:Recurrent 1_1
DTSTART;TZID=Israel Standard Time:20191023T080000
DTEND;TZID=Israel Standard Time:20191023T083000
CLASS:PUBLIC
PRIORITY:5
DTSTAMP:20191112T145232Z
TRANSP:OPAQUE
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SEQUENCE:0
LOCATION:
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-APPT-SEQUENCE:0
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-OWNERAPPTID:2117746898
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INTENDEDSTATUS:BUSY
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-ALLDAYEVENT:FALSE
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INSTTYPE:3
X-MICROSOFT-DONOTFORWARDMEETING:FALSE
X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:FALSE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

And it's no that that difficult to filter out modified occurrences as they have have `RECURRENCE-ID` that distinguish between master recurring and modified occurrence. The issue is then, when I trying to bring by using EWS all modified occurrences from that master : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.appointment.modifiedoccurrences?view=exchange-ews-api#Microsoft_Exchange_WebServices_Data_Appointment_ModifiedOccurrences and reqesting MIME for each mofified occurence brings MIME that contains again all modified ocurences for that master and now it's very difucult to filter out not relevant events, as I'm getting too many, for example with 1 master and 3 modified in total I'll get by MIME 10 events (1 master and 3 modified in each MIME request) and those are duplicates. Please see below example of MIME for modified occurrence (it contains same event twice, second time without some properties, while first event has RRULE definition together with RECURRENCE-ID that is comes in contradiction with iCal RFC)

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
METHOD:PUBLISH
PRODID:Microsoft Exchange Server 2010
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Israel Standard Time
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:16010101T020000
TZOFFSETFROM:+0300
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=10
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:16010101T020000
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0300
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=-1FR;BYMONTH=3
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
ORGANIZER;CN=Slava mailto:slava@domain.onmicrosoft.com
ATTACH:CID:C193186C7E6D4769FD7EB28C80DBC92443A1190C@eurprd01.prod.exchangel
 abs.com
DESCRIPTION;LANGUAGE=en-US:\n
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20200401T050000Z;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=WE;WKST=SU
UID:040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00800000000D263C072E37DD501000000000000000
 01000000021933B3497010A43A59A900692A1BE23
RECURRENCE-ID;TZID=Israel Standard Time:20191023T080000
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-US:Recurrent 1_1
DTSTART;TZID=Israel Standard Time:20191023T080000
DTEND;TZID=Israel Standard Time:20191023T083000
CLASS:PUBLIC
PRIORITY:5
DTSTAMP:20191112T145232Z
TRANSP:OPAQUE
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SEQUENCE:0
LOCATION;LANGUAGE=en-US:
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-APPT-SEQUENCE:0
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-OWNERAPPTID:2117746898
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INTENDEDSTATUS:BUSY
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-ALLDAYEVENT:FALSE
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INSTTYPE:3
X-MICROSOFT-DONOTFORWARDMEETING:FALSE
X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:FALSE
X-MICROSOFT-LOCATIONS:[]
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00800000000D263C072E37DD501000000000000000
 01000000021933B3497010A43A59A900692A1BE23
RECURRENCE-ID;TZID=Israel Standard Time:20191023T080000
SUMMARY:Recurrent 1_1
DTSTART;TZID=Israel Standard Time:20191023T080000
DTEND;TZID=Israel Standard Time:20191023T083000
CLASS:PUBLIC
PRIORITY:5
DTSTAMP:20191112T145232Z
TRANSP:OPAQUE
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SEQUENCE:0
LOCATION:
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-APPT-SEQUENCE:0
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-OWNERAPPTID:2117746898
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INTENDEDSTATUS:BUSY
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-ALLDAYEVENT:FALSE
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INSTTYPE:3
X-MICROSOFT-DONOTFORWARDMEETING:FALSE
X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:FALSE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Is there any way to get MIME that has only one event for each appointment in MIME ?

Thanks

Comment: This is how the ICS specification says things must work.  For the recurring series, there must be all the updates with SEQUENCE-NOs and RECURRENCE-ID's etc.        A quick google indicates that using get Item and the occurenceid may get you to a single instance of a recurring series.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/occurrenceitemid?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Thanks !!! Well, ICS specification is clear, but issue is with specific exception, while I can get it by get item on exception item id and it contains exactly one exception, then, when I'm asking for its MIME I'm getting all the series of exceptions, and if I have 10 exceptions, on each exception get MIME brings me 10 times of 10.